# bytearray to bitmap scenario

Tags: actionscript-3

I just have a ByteArray, not the bitmap. I am using the below code to convert to Bitmap, but I end up getting end of file error.

```
//rstream is the ByteArray I have
var bytes:ByteArray = rstream;
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,myPuzzle.width - 20,myPuzzle.height - 20);
var newBmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rect.width,rect.height,true,0xFFFFFFFF);
bytes.position = 0;
newBmd.setPixels(rect, bytes);
var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(newBmd);
```

Comment: What does `rstream` contains? How did you populate it?

Comment: Where does the bytearray come from ?

Comment: The ByteArray comes from one of my application which takes user input as image. I got it working just by using loader concept.have pasted the code below

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using a Loader.

```
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loading1);

    loader.loadBytes(rstream);
function loading1(e:Event):void
{
    var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(e.target.loader.content);

    myPuzzle.source = image;
}
```